# Getting "positional argument" error after adding "event" to a function

Tags: tkinter

I am trying to add keyboard bindings in my script. My script is basically a search function. Input name on entry box and it will lookup that name along with its data in the database and display it. I used a button in the menu for the search function. But i would like to add a keyboard shortcut, Ctrl+F for immediate access of the search function dialog box.

```
root = Tk()
root.geometry("950x550")
root.bind("<Control-f>", lookup_data)

def lookup_data():
    global search_entry, search
    search = Toplevel(root)
    search.title("Lookup Data")
    search.geometry("300x165")
    search.attributes('-topmost', True)

#Create label frame
search_frame = LabelFrame(search, text="Name:")
search_frame.focus_set()
search_frame.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

#Add entry box
search_entry = Entry(search_frame, font=("default", 15))
search_entry.focus_set()
search_entry.pack(pady=20, padx=20)

#Add a button
search_button = Button(search, text="Search Name", command=search_records)
search_button.pack(pady=20, padx=20)
```

The Ctrl+F key binding would only work if I edit the function lookup_data to lookup_data(event) as stated on tutorials that I've read online.
But after editing, the search button in the menu won't work. It gives me an error, **lookup_data() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'**

When I remove the "event" on lookup_data function, everything will work as intended except the key binding. What can I do so that both the search button and keyboard shortcuts work at the same time?

I'm new to python and just been learning the past few months. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since the callback for an event binding will be passed the event object when it is executed, whereas the callback for a button command will not be passed anything.

So if the same function is used for both cases, you need to define the function to have an argument *with default value*.  Then if no argument is passed when the function is executed, the default value will be passed.

Below is the modified `lookup_data()` having argument with default value:

```py
def lookup_data(event=None):
    ...
```